# Passing binding or arguments to ERB from the command line

Tags: ruby, templates, erb

I have been playing around with erb from the command line recently. I wanted to make a dirt simple erb template, for example the following:

```
<%- name = "Joe"; quality = "fantastic" -%>
Hello. My name is <%= name %>. I hope your day is <%= quality %>.
```

This works if I run

```
erb -T - thatfile.erb
```

what I want to do is to make `name` and `quality` be passable from command line arguments, so that I could do something like:

```
./thatfile.erb "Bill" "super"
```

from the bash prompt and do the same thing.

I am aware that I could write a ruby script that would just read that template in and then use `ERB.new(File.read("thatfile.erb")).result(binding)`, or writing the template after an `END` and doing likewise, but I'm looking for a more lightweight approach if it exists, because I don't want to write two files for each erb script that I create for this purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using unix, try following:

```
$ cat 1.erb
Hello. My name is <%= name %>. I hope your day is <%= quality %>.
$ (echo '<% name="Joe"; quality="fantastic" %>' && cat 1.erb) | erb

Hello. My name is Joe. I hope your day is fantastic.
```

Comment: upgrade the `echo` to `cat input.html.erb` and you got it

Answer (score 21):

Alternatively, you can use a ruby script and load it in as a library.

```rb
# vars.rb
@hello = 'kirk'
```

```erb
# template.html.erb
<div><%= @hello %></div>
```

```sh
$ erb -r './vars' template.html.erb
```

Comment: I like how this separates the data from the "logic" so to speak, and how you can simply stick to ruby.

Answer (score 17):

Please note that Ruby 2.2 and newer provide a much nicer solution that was implemented according to [this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10395):

```
erb var1=val1 var2=val2 my-template.erb
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle arrays with this syntax?

Comment: Use comma separated lists and split them. It only gets strings.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when the variables are referenced as @vars. Works ok without the @.

Comment: @Daniel that's what the documentation says too :)

Answer (score 16):

I went with the BASH command-line shortcut for environmental variables.

Outside:

```
STUFF=foo,bar erb input.html.erb >output.html
```

Inside:

```
<%
   stuff = ENV['STUFF'].split(',')
%>
```

After a few minutes e-searching I determined the other solutions are all variations on "write the erb wrapper command yourself." Could be wrong, but I ain't going back.