# Can I pass variables to be rendered by erb from the command line?

Tags: ruby, erb, chef-recipe

I have an `erb template` in a `chef cookbook` that configures my `vhost` for my `vagrant` environment and my `aws opsworks` environment.  I would like to utilize this template on my continuous integration server to generate the vhost for my non chef managed machines before it pushes it out.

Suppose I have the following erb:

```
<VirtualHost <%= @params[:http_host] %>:<%= @params[:http_port] || node['apache']['listen_ports'].first %>>
    ServerName <%= @params[:server_name] %>
    ServerAlias <% @params[:server_aliases].each do |a| %><%= a %> <% end %>

    DocumentRoot <%= @params[:docroot] %>
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I go about populating those variables if I wanted to call `erb` directly?

I know I can call `erb -r library vhost.conf.erb` to load a library to be leveraged, can set variables as an argument to erb or do I need to create a custom library.  If I need a custom library, how would that look?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can capture values in command line and add to recipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730833/how-i-can-capture-values-in-command-line-and-add-to-recipe)

Comment: @hek2mgl that question has answers for providing values in the scope of chef or passing to ruby as parameters. I'm curious if I can pass values to erb. In my case chef is aware of the values mostly from `ohai` and the rest is provided by the recipe. I want a separate host to be able to mock the result as if chef ran it on the target with details provided.

Comment: Ok, think I got the question now: Your erb is working when used inside chef, but you are now asking how to use the same erb - unchanged - directly from the commandline. Did I got you?

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, that's what i'm looking to do

Comment: I don't expect that this is possbile. You might need to write a small wrapper script which populates the variables as expected.

Comment: [Passing binding or arguments to ERB from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895306/passing-binding-or-arguments-to-erb-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I`Chef::Config[:node_name]` this will also help you https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef.html

Comment: @Ekult3k I'm not sure I understand how that would help.  I'm trying to process an erb written for a chef template outside of a chef context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Ruby 2.2 you can [set local variables in Erb from the command line](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/9e52416cd304c648e7bf49f1e77c81cd5adac506).

You would need to change your code to use local variables rather than instance variables. For example if you had (stripped down from your code):

```
<VirtualHost <%= http_host %>:<%= http_port %>>
```

You could then call it with:

```
$ erb http_host=http://example.com http_port=1234 my_file.erb
```

and the result would be:

```
<VirtualHost http://example.com:1234>
```

Comment: How would it work with an array though? Like in the OP example, `server_aliases` is expected to be an Array. When firing up `erb server_aliases=['test','bla'] template_name` that would return an error: `undefined method 'each' for "['test','bla']":String (NoMethodError)`